# What is the best way to track a drone's position using a chessboard grid? (Python & OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on a project with drones and I need to be able to track the position of the drone. I'm planning on doing this using a chessboard (only using it inside so GPS function is not available) and using indexes such as A1, A2, B1, C7 etc.

However, it's quite difficult to determine it's position doing it solely like this (say for example you push the drone and it passes a square). So I'd like to place tags on each square and do some sort of recognition on them. However, which tags would be the best to use? Since it's an 8*8 board, making it a total of 64 squares which means 64 tags.

Comment: What do you mean by *position*? The chessboard square which you are currently flying over, or the 3D coordinate of the drone in the room?

Comment: The chessboard square. Or would it be better to use the 3D coordinate (haven't got any experience with this)?

Comment: Depending on what you want, different methods are more suitable than others.

Answer (score 1):

Something that I used some time ago for a similar localization project is the [ARToolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/). We used [*markers*](http://www.artoolworks.com/support/library/Creating_and_training_new_ARToolKit_markers) which could be detected by the toolkit to perform an indoor localization.

**First case: camera NOT mounted on the drone**

For each square in your grid you could use a unique marker, and see if at any time it can be registered by the camera or not. If not, your drone is flying over it.

**Second case: camera mounted on the drone**

The ARToolkit allows you to calculate your distance to each tag. So if you always have at least three tags in your drone's view and the position of those tags are known, you can simply triangulate and find the drone's position.